# how to get values in JSON object and JSON array using java

Tags: java, arrays, object, json

I need to return a string in JSON to combine of json object and json array 
this is the example i need

```
 {

  "scode" : "62573000", "sname" : "Burn of right",
  "icd10" = [
    {"icode" : "T25.229?", "iname" : "Right foot"}
    {"icode" : "T25.22941?", "iname" : "left foot"}
  ],
  "refinement" = [
    {"rname" : "Refinement1"},
    {"rname" : "Refinement2"}
  ]
}
```

but i getting like this

```
{
    "icdcode": "T25.229?",
    "snomedcode": "62537000",
    "snomedname": "Second degree burn of foot (disorder)",
    "icdname": "Burn of second degree of unspecified foot, episode of care unspecified"
}
```

this is the code

```
oJsonAry = new JSONArray();

        while (resultSet.next())
        {           
            JSONObject oJsonOther = new JSONObject();
            JSONObject oJsonRefine = new JSONObject();
            hMapotherwise = new HashMap<String, String>();

            maprule = (resultSet.getString("mapRule"));
            if (maprule.matches("OTHERWISE TRUE")|| maprule.matches("TRUE"))
            {
                strSnomedCode=resultSet.getString("referencedComponentId");
                hMapotherwise.put("snomedcode", strSnomedCode);

                strSnomedDesc=resultSet.getString("sctName");
                hMapotherwise.put("snomedname", strSnomedDesc);

                strIcdCode=resultSet.getString("mapTarget");
                hMapotherwise.put("icdcode", strIcdCode);

                strIcdName=resultSet.getString("icdName");
                hMapotherwise.put("icdname", strIcdName);

                oJsonOther.putAll(hMapotherwise);
                oJsonAry.add(oJsonOther);
            }
                refid = resultSet.getInt("refid");
                pipe = resultSet.getString("mapRule").split("\\|");

                if (pipe.length > 1)
                {
                    bSubmit = true;
                    oJsonRefine.put("maprule", pipe);

                    oJsonAry.add(oJsonRefine);
                }


                if(oJsonAry != null) 
                {
                    strJSON = oJsonAry.toJSONString();
                }
        }
        }
```

what are the things which i need to change in my java code and i new to this so that i get stuck in this.could any one say how to overcome from this .finally i have to return in strJSON

Comment: Please include an actual [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

Your code doesn't make sense. Please try to be clearer in the next time.
First your Json is not in correct syntax.
The correct should be:

```
{
    "scode": "62573000",
    "sname": "Burn of right",
    "icd10": [{
        "icode": "T25.229?",
        "iname": "Right foot"
    }, {
        "icode": "T25.22941?",
        "iname": "left foot"
    }],
    "refinement": [{
        "rname": "Refinement1"
    }, {
        "rname": "Refinement2"
    }]
}
```

Second you want one type of return but you are using different variable names in your return example. ( We have to guess ).

With all these problems in your question, I tried to solve your problem, so lets see. You need to declare your arrays out side of your while.

```
        // Declare your arrays and main json outside of the while
    JSONArray arrayJsonIcd10 = new JSONArray();
    JSONArray arrayJsonRefinement = new JSONArray();
    JSONObject mainJsonObject = new JSONObject();

    while (resultSet.next())
    {           

        maprule = (resultSet.getString("mapRule"));
        if (maprule.matches("OTHERWISE TRUE")|| maprule.matches("TRUE"))
        {

            // create two objects inside the while to save your
            //objects that you need in the array
            JSONObject jsonObjectToScode = new JSONObject();
            JSONObject jsonObjectToRefinment = new JSONObject();

            strSnomedCode = resultSet.getString("referencedComponentId");
            mainJsonObject.put("snomedcode", strSnomedCode);

            strSnomedDesc = resultSet.getString("sctName");
            mainJsonObject.put("snomedname", strSnomedDesc);

            strIcdCode = resultSet.getString("mapTarget");
            jsonObjectToScode.put("icdcode", strIcdCode);

            strIcdName = resultSet.getString("icdName");
            jsonObjectToScode.put("icdName", strIcdName);

            arrayJsonIcd10.put(jsonObjectToScode);
        }
        refid = resultSet.getInt("refid");
        pipe = resultSet.getString("mapRule").split("\\|");

        if (pipe.length > 1)
        {
            bSubmit = true;
            jsonObjectToRefinment.put("rname", pipe);
            arrayJsonRefinement.put(jsonObjectToRefinment);

        }



    }
    mainJsonObject.put("icd10", arrayJsonIcd10 );
    mainJsonObject.put("refinement", arrayJsonRefinement);
    strJSON = mainJsonObject.toString();    

}
```

That's it but I am still confused how do you wanna obtain  ("scode" : "62573000", "sname" : "Burn of right") if the values are inside the while. I guess you'll need a other array to save this values.

Comment: yeah @tiagoribeirof its working fine . thanks and i new to json thats the problem